# Android ListAdapter not working with the onItemClickListener function

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I have the below code, but the onItemClickListener doesn't work,
can anyone help me what the problem could be?
I have also added the Override and the setClickable but the problem still exists.

```
public class Show extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.show);

...//Some codes in here

adapter = new MyAdapter(this, hadithList);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setClickable(true);    

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,     long id) {


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clickedItemString", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    });

}
```

Comment: post you adapter class

Answer (score 1):

In your `Activity`, you are first implementing `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` and than you are setting `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` to your `ListView`. You should choose one of the methods, not both.

If you choose to stick up implementing `OnItemClickListener`, you should add this to your `Activity` :

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clickedItemString", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and add this to your ListView : `list.setOnItemClickListener(this);`

If you choose to not implement `OnItemClickListener` just do :

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clickedItemString", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

This should work properly.